# What is the name for this front wheel steering type?

Tags: steering

So far I've found two types of steering aside from the classic direct steering ( Handlebar->Stem->Fork->Wheel rotating in head tube bearings (headset)) that eliminate the head tube, used in a few cargo bikes:

1. [Hub-center steering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hub-center_steering) moves the bearings inside the hub, compact and thus elegant, but requires complicated parts ([Elian](https://www.eliansteeringhub.com/), [Dan Titchmarsh](https://www.flickr.com/photos/titchmarsh/9626993019), [Bastiaen](https://customind-id.de/index.php/en/bike-home), [machined parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q3LqEMkzC8))
2. A four bar [linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(mechanical)) that is big(ger) but easy to build, with the tradeoff that there is no constant "virtual" axis of rotation, i.e. the wheel moves relative to the frame, depending on the linkage geometry ([Escargo](https://escargomotorcycle.com/aboutthebike/), [XYZ Cargo Bike](http://www.xyzcargo.com/cycles/)([steering](https://www.core77.com/posts/37237/Modular-Cargo-Bikes-with-Unusual-Steering-Mechanisms), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB_vSdX-_R4)), [Catan](https://bikerumor.com/catan-titanium-cargobike-corners-like-no-other-with-light-comfortable-ride/), [Veloader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1pq5NScTCs), [Cargonnect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFO7IWP_Etw&t=9s)).
   Of course that depends on the linkage - a design with more links allows a [fixed pivot](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/rotation-around-an-axis-outside-of-the-mechanism).

A simple sketch, top view:
[image]

It seems I got lucky there, the cyan trace shows that the motion is less than the tire width.

Youtuber `erik warnerin gambalgembelart` has collected a few more:

- ["DUAL PIVOT STEERING by TYPUS"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0SwWG5Tmg0)
- ["DUPLEX STEERING by SUPER RAT RACING"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7RJB7fl0WE)

Questions:

- Is there a name for this type of steering system?
- Are there more implementations / specimen of this?
- What are the design considerations / optimal geometry for this (zero displacement or is some displacement actually advantageous?)?
- Are there other designs (to eliminate the head tube bearing)?

Comment: Actually, I've come across another, from the maker of the Escargo: the [Y-Cycle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoDXtDymXc4) with 56 degrees of rake (horizontal fork).

Comment: Reer wheel steering linkage ([video](https://youtu.be/BFOLgY_eE_I?t=109)) on a recumbent, a comment calls it "trapezoidal steering linkage".

Comment: From your question I can not work out whether you indicate the steering of a Flevo bike/trike/high racer, where the front wheel is fixed into the front part of the frame and the frame has a pivot point in the middle of the total length.  Here is a link to a picture of one of those bikes: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bestand:Flevobike-air.jpg

Comment: @Willeke No, I don't mean center / articulated steering. Have a look at one of the examples listed in the 2nd bullet point, e.g. the [Catan](https://bikerumor.com/catan-titanium-cargobike-corners-like-no-other-with-light-comfortable-ride/), especially the section "Leading linkage arm steering system". The "arms" are shown in red in my sketch.

Comment: Might I suggest calling this "headless steering"?

Comment: "headless" would apply to hub center as well. I've found a few references to "duplex steering". And two more builds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W35AARfU90M https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZQwvfEk9BM